# Словозміна йменника 'нети'

Tags: відмінювання

Як  провідміняти слово 'нети'?

https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8

Нети, нетяк - небіж, племінник

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *Неть*, *неті* — за творами Семена Скляренка

У творах [Семена Скляренка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) (зокрема романах [«Святослав» (1959)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)) і [«Володимир» (1962)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD))) це слово відмінюють так:

| Відмінок | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Називний | неть (*— Я Антип, **неть** Минули й твій родич, посаднику, — відповів задушний чоловік.*) | неті (*…А за ними вже крокували **неті** Ігореві, бояри, священик Григорій.*) |
| Родовий, знахідний | нетя | нетів (*…Запросила вона їхати з собою ще й родичок своїх — посестрин, **нетів**, ще й жон князів чернігівського й переяславського.*) |
| Давальний | нетеві, нетю | нетям |
| Орудний | нетем (*— …І мені байдуже, кому ти доводишся **нетем**.*) | нетями |
| Місцевий | неті | нетях |
| Кличний | нетю | неті |

У творах вжито лише кілька форм (з усіх наведених у таблиці), але з них очевидно, що слово належить до м'якої групи (і відмінюється аналогічно слову *мудрець*), звідси й решта форм у таблиці.

Але твори Семена Скляренка — це художня література. Я не можу гарантувати, що він на 100% правильно реконструював це архаїчне/рідковживане слово. Також не виключено, що можливі кілька паралельних варіантів.

#### *Нети* — етимологічний словник

Якщо вірити «Етимологічному словнику української мови» в 7 томах (до речі, саме на його електронну версію, опубліковану на сайті goroh, Ви наводили посилання), це діалектне слово в називному відмінку множими має форму *нети*, тобто належить до твердої групи і мало б відмінюватися так:

- множина — нети, ¿нетів/нет/нетей? (тут не знаю, найімовірніше *нетів*), нетам, нетами, нетах;
- якщо в цього слова є однина, то — нет, нета, нетові/нету (паралельні форми), нетом, неті, ¿нете/нету? (тут не знаю).

Утім, не виключаю, що в словнику може бути описка/помилка. Зрештою, існує паралельний варіант *нетій*.

#### *Нетій*

- Згадується в різних роботах про застарілі слова, зокрема — [стаття «Застарілі слова» О. Тараненка](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um19.htm) (з [енциклопедії «Українська мова» (2000)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_(%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F))).
- Використовується в романі [Івана Білика](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) «Похорон богів» (1986).

Очевидно належить до м'якої групи:

| Відмінок | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Називний | нетій (*Стара видибала до Красних воріт, а там уже її **нетій** Людвік…*) | нетії |
| Родовий, знахідний | нетія (*Вона це мовила таким голосом, що я одразу збагнув, як вона остерігається брата й **нетія** Людвіка.*) | нетіїв |
| Давальний | нетієві, нетію | нетіям |
| Орудний | нетієм | нетіями |
| Місцевий | нетії | нетіях |
| Кличний | нетію | нетії |

P.S.: Цитати в художній літературі знайдено за допомогою [Генерального регіонально анотованого корпусу української мови](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8).

Comment: Tak rozumêju, *netı* nemaʼ v korpusax? A tak, perexôd *netij* v *netj* pokı zdajeʼ sja logičnım: *Natalija* > *Natalja*, ale pokı ne zhadaju čolovêčıj prıklad. Ce točno ne cifrova pomılka, bo na paperovomu tež [*netı*](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf#page=78).

Comment: Vse, zhadav čolovêčıj: *Vasılij* > *Vasılj*, takož možna zustrêtı *Hrıhorij* > *Hrıhorj*. Ale ce ne pracjuje na 100 %: *Jevhenij* > *Jevhen*. Pošukı v krıvıx [korpusax](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=нети) čı prosto v Gugelê, na žalj, uskladnujutj sja slovom *netı* ščo vôd [*inter*]*net* abo obêrvanımı slovamı, ščo zakônčujutj sja na *netı*, jak *bag-netı*, *pla-netı*, *kabi-netı* itd.